# Python cv2 returns numpy array of other size than specified

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I got a little program where I want to stream images from my laptop's camera and process them (irrelevant here) and then output it to my screen. My current code looks as follows:

## Python 3.7.1 / cv2 4.1.0

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 200)

while True:
    frame_created, frame = cap.read()

    print(frame.shape)  # writes (360, 640, 3)

    cv.imshow('frame', self.frame)
    key = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Now I wonder why the returned frame has the shape shown above since I specified other frame height and frame width with `cap.set()`? Am I missing something here or is it a bug in the current version? The output frame does have the 'wrong' shape as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your camera supports 300x200 natively, asking for it will only get you close. The OpenCV docs could be clearer on this, instead of leaving you to figure out what

> Effective behaviour depends from device driver and API Backend

means.

See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) for a tiny bit more.